# Defining how long a list can be in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

So I'm new to Haskell and i'm trying to define a list which is a Max of 4 elements long.
so far I have `type IntL = [Int,Int,Int,Int]`
but I was thinking there must be a better/proper way of doing this.
Is there?

Comment: `type IntL = [Int,Int,Int,Int]` shouldn't work at all.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz In GHC 7.10 it suggests enabling `DataKinds` so to exploit the type-to-kinds lifting. If one does so then one gets `IntL :: [*]`, i.e. `IntL` is a list of types. Unfortunately, this is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is problematic in Haskell because phantom types encoding sizes need proper compiler support (otherwise it's pretty annoying to use), and type nats in GHC appeared somewhat recently.

That being said [libraries](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-vector-0.6.3.1/docs/Data-Vector-Fixed.html) [exist](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixed-list), just to give you an idea.

Alternatively, just use a tuple.

Comment: It depends. There is a lot of difference between a list of 4 elements and a list of MAXIMUM 4 elements.

Answer (score 5):

it might look stupid and it certainly does not scale but what about

```
data Max4 a
   = Empty
   | One a
   | Two a a
   | Three a a a
   | Four a a a a
```

with `type IntL = Max4 Int`? It's basic, you should be able to understand it and you can learn a lot by implementing operations on it.

Answer (score -1):

Basic Haskell Types are not so powerful as to encode the maximum length of a list. In order to do that, you must rely on extensions such as GADTs and Phantom Types and yet it is not straightforward as well.

If you are really a newbie, I advice you to learn other basic concepts like Monads, IO and other idioms.

This site is a very good reading for an initial approach to Haskell:

http://learnyouahaskell.com

Comment: I've downvoted. The answer appears to be incorrect (e.g. `Maybe (a, Maybe (a, Maybe (a, Maybe a)))` is a pretty basic Haskell type, and looks a lot like a list with a maximum length), and the comment redirecting the user to monads and `IO` looks off-target to me.

Comment: Fair. My answer was actually a non-answer which may not be the perfect fit for Stackoverflow yet I find it a one more suitable for a newbie.